# Why is /proc/loadavg not factoring in the amount of cores on a linux system?

Tags: linux, cpu, proc

Why is it on linux systems with multiple processor cores (most systems of today), that the loadavg doesn't compensate for this?

When 1 core on my system is being utilized by 1 process, the loadavg shows 1.00. shouldn't it be 1.00 when all cores are being used by 1 process? or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because load average is the average number of processes running, waiting to run, or waiting for disk I/O to complete.  Nowhere in that description does it mention how many processors you have.  Load average actually is only partially related to cpu load anyway -- you could have a load average of 10 and still have a cpu load of 0.

Perhaps you are looking for a number that is a cpu utilization percentage... but load average is not that.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about that at all, now i understand it much better.